# Passing constants out of a function - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-queue

I hope this doesn't sound dumb but I'm trying to put:

```
let lowercasedQuery = query.lowercased()
            
             let usersNew = users.filter({ $0.fullname.lowercased().contains(lowercasedQuery) || $0.username.contains(lowercasedQuery) })
```

into the DispatchQueue function but obviously, since they are constants declared in the function, the function is out of scope for the return line.

```
func filteredUsers(_ query: String) -> [User] {
        
        
        let delay = 3.3
    
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay)
        {
            
        }
            
            let lowercasedQuery = query.lowercased()
            
             let usersNew = users.filter({ $0.fullname.lowercased().contains(lowercasedQuery) || $0.username.contains(lowercasedQuery) })
        
        return usersNew
    }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot return a value from a function that does something `async`! Please read http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/ and the two articles that follow it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `asyncAfter`? It looks like an attempt to work around an asynchronous network request. If yes, don't do that, it's horrible practice, and it causes exactly the behavior you try to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a closure... more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67324059/14351818). Instead of `return`, call the completion handler closure.

```
func filteredUsers(_ query: String, completion: @escaping (([User]) -> Void)) {
    let delay = 3.3
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
        let lowercasedQuery = query.lowercased()
        let usersNew = self.users.filter({ $0.fullname.lowercased().contains(lowercasedQuery) || $0.username.contains(lowercasedQuery) })
        completion(usersNew)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
viewModel.filteredUsers(searchText) { users in
    print(users) /// get your users here!
}
```

---

If you are trying to return `users` inside another function, it won't work. You also need to a add a closure to *that* function:

```
                                   /// another closure here
func mainFunction(_ query: String, completion: @escaping (([User]) -> Void)) {
    viewModel.filteredUsers(query) { users in
        completion(users) /// equivalent to `return users`
    }
}

mainFunction("searchText") { users in
    print(users) /// get your users here!
}

/// NOT `let users = mainFunction("searchText")`
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
I call the function in a different view using:
return viewModel.filteredUsers(searchText)
But i now get an error, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @TheLegend27 you wouldn't be able to use `return` there either. See my edit

Comment: thanks for the help, I get this error when trying to add it "Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type '[User]'". I'm calling it inside this "var users: [User] {}" as the return was in here before. Sorry for making this confusing.

Comment: @TheLegend27 Did you do `return viewModel.filteredUsers(searchText)` again? Completion handlers are asynchronous (they are delayed), so you can't use `return` anywhere. I'll add an example in my answer. But you should really check out the [article](http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/) @matt sent.